# Blazor ApexCharts Annotations do not show in graph

Tags: blazor, apexcharts

I am using BlazorApexCharts and trying to add annotations to a line graph. **Problem:*** The X-Axis annotation does not show. Here is the code for the XAxis: *(Note - to assist me with error-checking, I am creating each object as I go, rather than using the more typical initialization syntax.)* Debugging indicates the Annotations object is populated correclty - to me, anyway. I used a similar pattern for a Y-Axis annotation, and it worked fine. Would appreciate suggestions on what needs modifying.

```
       SecOptions.Annotations = new(); //SecOptions is object for all options for the graph
       {--- code for Y-Axis annotation goes here --}

       SecOptions.Annotations.Xaxis = new();  //create list for XAxisAnnotation objects
       AnnotationsXAxis X1 = new();  //create new XAxis annotation X1, set its properties
       X1.X = 2151;  //this is a value on X Axis
       X1.BorderWidth = 2;
       X1.BorderColor = "#C83ACA";
       X1.StrokeDashArray = 5;
       X1.Opacity = 0.9d;
       X1.Label = new Label { Text = "Current Year", Style = new Style { FontSize = "18px;" } };
       SecOptions.Annotations.Xaxis.Add(X1); //Add XAxis Annotation to list
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. Because I had declared the X axis as "XAxisType="XAxisType.Category", the position for the X annotation needed to be a string, not an integer. So, changing 'X1.X = 2151;' to 'X1.X = "2151";' is all that was needed.